# jQuery load event in Chrome returns width/height values of zero in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, popup

Creating a popup window from main page with window.open, the child/popup page uses the onload event which should display it's width/height. However in Chrome this will always result in 0. Checking both the window's and document's width/height (with or without jQuery) will only return 0. Oddly enough loading the child page in a tab by itself will always report the width/height correctly.

Is this correct behavior? Is there something wrong with the load event? With Chrome? Is there another event I can wait for to assure the width/height properties in particular are set?

If a timeout is placed in the onload you will likely get the correct values. But it seems to just be a guessing game about how long to wait before you check the width/height. Is there no way to wait for a particular event to **know for sure** that the width/height of the child window are set in Chrome?

Quick demo below with both pages. Hoping someone maybe has some solution, which doesn't involve guessing at an indeterminate amount of time to put into setTimeout.

**Edit**: Forgot to mention, I have tested this on Chrome versions 14/15.

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>main</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Pop" onclick="window.open('http://localhost:8085/social_test/test.html', 'namedWnd', 'width=320,height=240')" />
    </body>
</html>
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function(){
                var report = function() {
                    alert($(window).width() + " x " + $(window).height());
                };
                report();
                //window.setTimeout(report, 1000);
            });
            // without any jquery
            /*window.onload = function() {
                var report = function() {
                    alert(window.innerWidth + " x " + window.innerHeight);
                    // or document's size
                    //alert(window.document.documentElement.clientWidth
                    //  + " x " + window.document.documentElement.clientHeight);
                };
                report();
                //window.setTimeout(report, 1000);
            };*/
        </script>
    </head>
    <body/>
</html>
```

Comment: what if you add some content to the body?

Comment: Your code worked as-is basically for me in Chrome 16 -- display the correct dimensions.

Comment: This actually seems to work so long as I check the document's width/height.

Comment: @Nicholi -- actually scratch that, I think there is an issue now. Maybe a jquery bug not sure though.

Comment: @david Does it only work the first time you open the popup? Then stops? I think roberkules hit the nail here. If i put something in the document body and check $(document).width()/height() it seems to be ok. At least in Chrome 14/15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use $(document) instead of $(window) : http://api.jquery.com/height/

I've used it in a pop app for myself, and it works, with no timeout or anything

Comment: Tried again with $(document) just now, and it seems to indeterminately return the correct values. If I continue to open the popup (after closing it) it stops reporting correct values. Also just wondering, what version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Just realized that since my document body is really empty, obviously it will only report 0. Adding something into <body> and I seem to get always reproducible answers. Thanks.

Comment: @Nicholi -- why should $(window) obviously return 0? From the jQuery docs:

"$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport"

The browser viewport size should not be affected by what is inside it.

Comment: yeah what david says is true, but there are diffenerent rulings when it comes to pop up windows I have noticed, which is really annoying

Comment: @david I was referring to checking the $(document).width/height. Not the $(window). And my document body in the examples is empty, add something to it and then $(document).width/height return real values. Why $(window) doesn't work at all (without a timeout), I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

It might not always be right to use `$(document)` instead of `$(window)`

Solution: Everyone with (such) jQuery problems should be directly pointed to double-check whether the DTD is really pointing to the following DTD
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd

Reference: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12426

Comment: Will have to check again what the state of this problem is now. Though as quite a few different folks pointed out my problem was solved (for the most part) by simply added something to the document body.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).load(function(){
    function report() {
        alert($(window).width() + " x " + $(window).height());
    };
    report();
});
```

Comment: I had actually tried that originally, the event doesn't seem to fire at all. Can the document have a load event?

Comment: Which is it $(document).ready or $(document).load? I figured waiting for the full window to be loaded would be wiser than any of the ready events (either window or document). Since the issue seemed to be waiting for Chrome to finish what it was doing (the setTimeouts). $(document).ready using the $(window).width/height functions doesn't work anyways.